# Data Transfer Objects - Exceptions

Tags: c#, dto

I am using the DTO pattern in my application. I have not created any dedicated assemblers to build dto's from my domain entities, instead I pass the domain entity to the DTO and allow it to build and return an appropriately constructed DTO.

Is this approach ok?

Is it acceptable for DTO's to throw exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to comment on this without more details, and in any case, this probably depends on your situation and personal preferences.

One thing that strikes me though, is that this might expose some of your inner workings to a client. Assuming for instance, that you do this by passing a domain entity as a parameter to a constructor in a DTO-class, that constructor will also be visible to a client receiving the DTO, and so will the domain entity class, since it will need to be known for the DTO for it to be able to accept it as a parameter (a reference to it must exist for it to be a valid parameter).

I don't know if this is a problem for you (or if this is even how you've implemented your logic), but it might be worth thinking about..

***Update:***

As for throwing exceptions, and logic in general in DTO's - my personal preference would be to keep this sort of thing at an absolute minimum. Again, this may be a little subjective, but I can think of at least two reasons:

**Basic separation of concerns:** The DTO should be a simple transfer object, and nothing more.

**Avoiding dependencies:** In my experience, if you add logic in places like this, you will eventually end up adding references that you will regret later. Since you will probably want to use and refer to a DTO class from several different projects, you don't want references from the DTO to either one of those projects, as that would implicitly add references *between* those projects. Avoiding any logic at all in a DTO will guarantee that it is not dependent on anything outside of its own assembly.